# How to search in a string containing words, three letter month and two digit year for the month and year and convert them to a date in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a table in which one of the columns contains strings of the following format:

```
ENGLISH.JOHN.BROWN.MAR.92
GERMAN.TIM.OLIVER.JAN.95
```

I need to get the month and year and convert them to a date of the format '`01-MAR-92`'and '`01-JAN-95`', the goal is to sort the data in the table based on this month and year?

I am new to sql so I was not sure where to start. Thank you very much for any advice provided.

I tried using order by but the column gets ordered alphabetically.

Comment: I am using Toad.

Comment: Toad can be used with different dbms products. Which one are you connected to?

Comment: I am using Toad for Oracle. I hope that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your month-year data always has the format `MON-YY` then you don't need to use (slow) regular expressions and can just use simple string functions to get the last 6 character sub-string and parse that as a date:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table( your_column ) AS
  SELECT 'ENGLISH.JOHN.BROWN.MAR.92' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GERMAN.TIM.OLIVER.JAN.95'  FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE( SUBSTR( your_column, -6 ), 'MON.RR' ) AS date_value
FROM   your_table;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | DATE_VALUE |
> | :--------- |
> | 01-MAR-92  |
> | 01-JAN-95  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=380395e18075423cb0df4eba0d5dd0b9)*

If you can have variable length months (sometimes character and sometimes digits) then you can count backwards through the string and find the second to last dot in the list:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE( SUBSTR( your_column, INSTR( your_column, '.', -1, 2 ) + 1 ), 'MON.RR' )
         AS date_value
FROM   your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr with instr as following.

```
Select


to_date(substr(your_string,instr(your_string, '.',1,3)+1), 'mon.yy') 
from your_table
```

Cheers!!

Comment: `YY` might not be the most appropriate format model as it will map `92` to the current century (i.e. `2092`) when the data probably refers to the end of the last century (i.e. `1992`).

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use `regexp_substr()` analytic function together with `to_char()` and `to_date()` functions :

```
with tab(str) as
(
 select 'ENGLISH.JOHN.BROWN.MAR.92' from dual union all
 select 'GERMAN.TIM.OLIVER.JAN.95'  from dual   
)
select to_date(
                regexp_substr(str,'[^.]+',1,4)||regexp_substr(str,'[^.]+',1,5),'MONRR' ) 
    as "MyDate"
  from tab;

MyDate
---------
01-MAR-92
01-JAN-95
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3c3914ae04d5c79f1bc3c57701831350)</kbd>

*Prefer using `MONRR` pattern instead of `MONYY`, since `to_date(regexp_substr(str,'[^.]+',1,4)||regexp_substr(str,'[^.]+',1,5),'MONYY')` conversion may yield unexpected results such as `01.03.2092` and `01.01.2095` instead of `01.03.1992` and `01.01.1995` .*